# Result of SELECT MAX(id) is null

Tags: sqlite, dart

On the database open, I inserted 5 records into the Expense table. Then I removed all 5 records one by one. 
And before I insert new entry I check max inserted id. For some reason it's null. What's wrong?

```
var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) as last_inserted_id FROM Expense");
final maxID = result.first["last_inserted_id"];
print('maxID:$maxID'); //maxID:null
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no rows in the table, there is no maximum defined. What you rather should do is look for the ID sequence number of the table to find out what the next ID will be. That information is usually stored in some meta table of the DB.

`SELECT seq FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='Expense';`

Comment: E/SQLiteLog(25732): (1) no such table: SQLITE_SEQUENCE

Comment: @rozerro Read https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html and https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab